# Browser back with conditions

Tags: javascript, button, back

```
function goBack() {
   window.history.back();
}
```

Hi guys I'd like to include a simple page back button - to all my websites theme pages and the above simple (window.history.back) would work a treat 95% of the time... but i'd like to add 2 extra conditions...

1. If the browser didn't have history...
2. If the previous page wasn't already from within my site 'https://example.com/'. and all of its sibling pages such as 'https://example.com/contact/'.

So that if you'd arrived directly at a content page on the site from Google and clicked the button, you wouldn't then go back...

**INSTEAD** in either of these 2 parameters outlined above, I'd just like the button to take the user back to my homepage. hard coded url 'https://example.com'.

Please help, I'm pretty new to JS, I'm trying to write if statements to do this, but don't know how to query the referring pages.

Thanks in advance.
Dan.

Comment: What have you tried? Browser history is well-trodden ground. You're expected to make an effort and show us what is and isn't working.

Comment: I'm also curious why you're replicating what the browser back button and (presumably) your logo link already do. Why do you think that will be a useful feature? I can see it at a specific point in a form sequence, for example, but....

Comment: do you tried `if ( window.history.back() == null ) ` or isspace() method ?

Comment: At the bottom corner of every page I have a floating (chevron-up) that animates users to the top of the page and I'd just like to have another  (chevron-left) to return users to the previous page - but ONLY if the previous page was already from within my website, if the previous page was from a search engine or from a referring website, I'd like this to take them to my homepage.